# Length of the endomorphism ring of a module of finite length

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a commutative Artian local ring and $M$ a finitely generated faithful $A$-module. Let $\text{End}_A(M)$ denote the ring of all $A$-linear endomorphisms of $M$. Is $l_A(\text{End}_A(M))\ge l_A(M)$, where $l_A(N)$ denotes the length of an $A$-module $N$? I suspect the equality to hold iff $M$ is cyclic (the if part is clear).

Comment: At first glance, I expect this to be false in general, though I don't know a counterexample off the top of my head. At least your suspicion about equality is false; if $E(k)$ is the injective hull of the residue field of $A$ then it is well-known that $E(k)$ is faithful, that $l_A(E(k))=l_A(A)$, and that $\operatorname{End}_A(E(k)) \cong A$, but $E(k)$ is cyclic if and only if $R$ is Gorenstein.

Comment: Thank you. It's time to revisit Bruns & Herzog.